# .NET Collection that is a struct

Tags: c#, collections

Here's an interesting question ... is there a collection that **is** a struct somewhere in the .net framework?

Just to clarify, all of the existing collections (List, array, etc.) are all reference types ... even if you set the generic parameter to a value type. But I want to know if there's a way I can make a collection that is actually a struct. I obviously wouldn't plan on passing this around (which would result in a ton of copying) ... I'd keep it as a private member in my class (internal state) so it's only defined once. The idea is that I would be able to avoid invoking the garbage collector just to make a small collection (think XNA).

Assuming one does not exist, a secondary part of the question is, what would be the ideal data structure for this. linked list?

Comment: Theoretically you can create a struct and implement IList or Icollection interfaces so you still have a value type. Not sure if it would help much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, such a type does not exist and it would not be a good idea. Structs should be small immutable value types according to the Microsoft guidelines.

From the [Value Type Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23b5415.aspx):

> - Act like primitive types.
> - Have an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - Are immutable.
> - Value semantics are desirable.

It would be difficult to implement a linked list as a value type because linked lists are typically defined recursively. This works fine:

```
class Node<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public Node<T> Next;
}
```

But this fails because structs have a fixed size and that size must be known when the struct is defined:

```
struct Node<T>
{
    public T Value;

    // Error: Struct member 'Node<T>.Next' of type 'Node<T>'
    // causes a cycle in the struct layout
    public Node<T> Next; 
}
```

Comment: Though, Eric Lippert has a whole blog series about immutable collection types :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying ... ok, didn't know that would result in a compilation error. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a struct that is a collection. `BitVector32` is a struct and acts like a collection of 32 booleans, or 4 bytes or 2 shorts. It's pretty handy when you want to do bittwidling but don't want to think too much about creating masks and such.

Also if you actually plan on rolling your own, be warned that if you make it implement something like `IList<Int32>` you should never send it to code that reads like

```
public static void SomeMethod(IList<Int32> list)
{
       ....
}
```

As that will box it and each member access will most likely lead to boxing instead send it to a method that has this signature::

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(T list) where T:IList<Int32>
{
       ....
}
```

As the second example will emit the `constrained` opcode before each callvirt which will avoid boxing when invoking struct members. Good luck though.

Comment: ahh, but I guess the deal there is that it's a collection of a known size. I was looking for something a bit more ambiguous in size

Comment: Eh somewhat. There is also `ArgIterator` and `__arglist` which are 2 very strange barely supported items. You can also fake it by using interfaces to access your next node member, but then your boxing which sucks.

Comment: Good point, although I would change the *never* in your `you should never send it to code` to *sometimes not* :)

Comment: @nawfal If you are dealing with non-primitive structs in code designed for performance (e.g. games) it is best to be extremely cautious. Using `ref` parameter passing, avoid boxing. Using the constrained generic method construct in .net 4.5 is actually even better, as it does some genuine magic and devirtualize the interface calls! This allows for inlining of method body when the JIT deems appropriate. This also has some benefit as you can avoid the cost sometimes of the ref passing style used for struct instance methods.

Comment: @MichaelB yes, but as I said these are rarities in grand scheme of things. I noted it there given the generalized statement in your answer. Btw, what do you mean by `constrained generic method construct in .net 4.5`?

Answer (score 0):

And there is [SPAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-7.0), in dotNetCore since v 2.1